# NSMutableArray not retaining object after for loop

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, sdwebimage

I'm trying to add to a `NSMutableArray` some `UIImages` downloaded with [`SDWebImage`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) in order to display them later.

The problem I'm having is that initially the array stores the objects in the completion loop, but then it loses them.

The array is initialized in `viewDidLoad`, and it has a property declared in `.h` file.

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

    for (int i = 0; i<urlsArray.count; i++ )
    {
        [manager downloadImageWithURL:[urlsArray objectAtIndex:i] options:SDWebImageDelayPlaceholder progress:nil 
            completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) 
            {
                [self.photosArray addObject:image];
                //Here are stored into self.photosArray
            }];
    }
   //Here the photosArray is empty
```

But after re-entering the view, the objects are there. Really weird. It doesn't display them at the first try.

I've already searched here and on Google, but nothing really helped me.

Comment: You have your order of events wrong. The photos array is empty because none of your completion blocks have run yet.

Comment: Oh, I meant to put the photosArray empty outside the for loop. My bad, edited the question

Comment: You can't read asynchronous code from top to bottom and expect it to execute in that order. It could take a very long time for each image to load and it's completion block will only execute when it's completed.

Comment: Yeah indeed I saw that the first NSLog that showed up was the one with the empty array, then the one in the for loop showed up. Should I need to move the code somewhere else or is there a sort of workaround to fill the array?

Comment: Your array fills fine. But the block that runs the filling code is executed AFTER the completion of the `downloadImageWithURL:options:progress:completed:` method. The block does not run immediately when you pass it into the method. A completion block is basically like telling the method that "do whatever you have to, and run this piece of code when you're done". Then the method will execute in the background, and the program continues to the next line, where the array is empty because the block was not executed yet (because the method has not completed it's stuff yet in the background).

Comment: Put the code that needs the filled array into a method, then call that method from inside the block after filling the array.

Comment: Or even better, pass a completion callback block into you method.

Comment: @adam10603 I tried as you suggested and the array is now filled. The problem is that I still need to exit the view and re-enter it again for the images to actually show

Comment: You shouldn't need to exit and reload the view once your images are downloaded. Once the image array is filled, you can use it to display what you need.

Comment: Solved it! @adam10603 Post your answer, I'll accept it! Thanks for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The completion block is only executed when the method finishes it's job. Once you call the method, the program continues to the next line, where your array is still empty. The method does it's things in the background at this point. The completion block is executed later in time.

To receive your filled array, you should call the piece of code that needs the filled array from inside the completion block.

Comment: Somehow I didn't notice the for loop there. This makes things different. From your completion block, call a method that does the following: increment an integer by 1, then check if it's is equal to the desired number of elements (in your case `urlsArray.count`). If it is, call another method which has the code in it that needs the filled array.
This is required because all the method calls from the for loop will execute in the background, and you can't tell when are all of those done running. This way, a simple counter method keeps track of how many elements your array has, and act accordingly

Answer (score 1):

After the call to `[manager downloadImageWith...]`, `photosArray` shouldn't necessarily be filled since you add objects to it in the `completed` block, which is happening Asynchronously upon completion of the connection.

Comment: Problem is that I actually need to fill it up, but I can't do it

Comment: You are adding the images to your array fine. Your problem is that you're expecting asynchronous code to run synchronously.